# Challenges setting up virtual environment with Win10/VSCODE/Anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio, git-clone, virtual-environment

I am new to Python and I need to clarify my set-up and how to set up virtual environments properly.

I am in Windows 10 and using VSCODE and managing all of my packages with Anancoda Navigator 2.3.2.  My Anaconda terminal settings are as follows:

Target: %windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda

Start in: %HOMEPATH%

When I start my VSCODE I choose an interpreter as follows SHFT+CNTL+P and I chose "Python 3.9.12('base') C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe

I don't really understand the concept of virtual environments.  So when I see project examples that involve the creation of these virtual environments I typically don't do anything. I simply open up my VSCODE and create a python file, choose my Python interpreter and start coding.  When I need to install packages to support a project I typically go into my Anaconda terminal and type:

```
conda install [packagename]
```

And this is all I typically do and I run through various projects and run them within VSCODE.  And this has all worked well to date.

Where I am now running into issues is that I have cloned a Github project and the readme file has instructions that are now highlighting my blind spots on both my current set-up and virtual environments.  They say as follows:

##### Create a Python environment

Using `conda`:

```bash
cd [projectfoldername]
conda create -n xxxxx-env python=3.8
conda activate xxxxx-env
```

The problem here is that if I type "cd [projectfoldername]" I get an error stating "The system cannot find the path specified." I am assuming this is because my VSCODE terminal directory prompt is:

(base) C:\Users\MyName>

Which is my %HOMEPATH% setting in Anaconda terminal

But the actual location of the cloned Github project is actually deeper in that directory in sub folders.
C:\Users\MyName\WWWWWWWW\XXXXXX\YYYYYY\ZZZZZZZ[projectfoldername]

Now to be clear, all of my existing and future python projects will be in that directory where this cloned projects resides:
C:\Users\MyName\WWWWWWWW\XXXXXX\YYYYYY\ZZZZZZZ

But that is not the directory setting for my Anaconda terminal "start in" directory.

And this had me wondering if I should simply change the "start in" settings in the Anaconda terminal from %HOMEPATH% to C:\Users\MyName\WWWWWWWW\XXXXXX\YYYYYY\ZZZZZZZ.

However, I am wondering if there is more to it than this and whether this will create other issues that I am unaware of.

Can someone provide me with the best path forward so that I can implement the example provided above and allow me to properly set-up virtual environments with that set-up for all projects going forward.

Thank-you in advance!